# How to remove certain characters in a string?

Tags: swift

The string value varies sometimes it's

93.93% - 94.13, 85.34, %74.90, 88.21%

I just need to extract the double value like this.

93.93, 85.34, 74.90, 88.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract numbers from your string like this:

```
let sourceString = "93.93% - 94.13, 85.34, %74.90, 88.21%"

func getNumbers(from string : String) -> [String] {
    let pattern = "((\\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\\.[0-9]+)?)|((\\+|-)?\\.?[0-9]+)" // Change this according to your requirement
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))

    let result = matches.map { (match) -> String in
        let range = Range(match.range, in: string)!
        return String(string[range])
    }

    return result
}

let numberArray = getNumbers(from: sourceString)
print(numberArray)
```

Result:

```
["93.93", "94.13", "85.34", "74.90", "88.21"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using a regex like this for example :

```
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}
```

This regex find all string that match two numbers, then a dot and two numbers again.

Comment: What a great idea ! Very smart !

Answer (score 0):

for each value such as `var str='%74.90';` use this line -

```
var double=str.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); })[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scanner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) to scan the values. `Scanner` is highly configurable and designed for scanning string and numeric values from loosely demarcated strings. Below is the example:

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
let scanner = Scanner(string: "93.93% - 94.13, 85.34, %74.90, 88.21%")
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = characterSet
var numStr: NSString?
while scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: characterSet, into: &numStr) {
    print(numStr ?? "")
}
```

**Output:**

```
93.93
94.13
85.34
74.90
88.21
```

It is easier to understand comparatively regex.